# AngularJS expression in style doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an SPA using AngularJS (Angular 1) with a bunch of table elements that look like this, but the first line is my issue:

```
<td align="right" style="background-color:  {{computeBgColor(name, 60)}}">
    <div ng-if="totalCount(name, 60) > 0">
        <div ng-if="failureCount(name, 60) > 0">
            <a href="#" ng-click="openErrorCounts(name, '60')">
                <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{totalCount(name, 60)}} records; yellow: {{yellowThreshold(name, 60)}}%; red: {{redThreshold(name, 60)}}%">
                    {{successRate(name, 60) | percentage:2}} | {{avgTxTime(name, 60) | number:2}} ms
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="failureCount(name, 60) == 0">
            <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{totalCount(name, 60)}} records; yellow: {{yellowThreshold(name, 60)}}%; red: {{redThreshold(name, 60)}}%">
                {{successRate(name, 60) | percentage:2}} | {{avgTxTime(name, 60) | number:2}} ms
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome.  In Internet Explorer 11, the value is ignored.

What are some reasonable strategies for resolving this?  I noticed that there is an "ng-style", but the semantics of that are very different. It's not clear how I would translate something like this to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is it :

```
 ng-style="{'background-color':computeBgColor(name, 60)}"
```